Shortest possible valid PEM-encoded CA certificate
The challenge is to create the shortest possible PEM-encoded CA certificate. The PEM format is specified in rfc7468 (section 5.1 shows an example certificate), and the structure of certificate data (X.509) is given by rfc5280 (section 4).
The score of an answer is the total length in bytes of its output certificate, with a lower score being the goal.
It needs to be valid, so for example it must be possible to decode it using openssl.
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ca-cert.pem

Example answer, given in rfc7468 in figure 6, 814 bytes
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


I think this challenge could probably do with a little more of an explanation of PEM-encoded CA certificates.

166 bytes
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MFAwRgIBADADBgEAMAAwHhcNNTAwMTAxMDAwMDAwWhcNNDkxMjMxMjM1OTU5WjAAMBgwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEBAwkAMAYCAQACAQAwAwYBAAMBAA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

This “certificate”, generated by hand with ascii2der, has an empty issuer, empty subject, 0-bit RSA public key, no extensions, and empty signature with algorithm null, but openssl x509 does load it:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
        Signature Algorithm: 0.0
        Issuer: 
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 1950 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 23:59:59 2049 GMT
        Subject: 
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (0 bit)
                Modulus: 0
                Exponent: 0
    Signature Algorithm: 0.0
    Signature Value:

(I think we need much more clarification about what “valid” means. After such clarification is provided, I’m happy to delete or revise this.)

"empty signature with algorithm null"; did not know it's possible to go this far; about specifying "valid", I guess the original "openssl x509 loads it" is the best I can come up with; my original inspiration for the challenge was needing to have dummy cert string for some tests that do cursory validation of the certificate but don't actually use it for anything, and this fits it just fine. If anyone has an idea for a better criterion (leading to more interesting competition), feel free to post their own challenge!

"opensssl x509 loads it" looks like a fine spec to me

Python's cryptography, 290 bytes
I could not beat my previous result using openssl req, so I switched to Python's cryptography module, which is somehow able to produce even shorter certs. I again used elliptic curve-based certs because the curves are smaller than RSA. openssl is still happy to load such certificate.
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ed25519
from cryptography.x509 import CertificateBuilder
from cryptography import x509

import datetime

def generate_minimal_certificate() -> bytes:
    private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.generate()

    subject = x509.Name([
        # x509.NameAttribute(x509.NameOID.COMMON_NAME, 'localhost')
    ])

    cert = (
        CertificateBuilder()
        .subject_name(subject)
        .issuer_name(subject)
        .public_key(private_key.public_key())
        .serial_number(1)
        .not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC))
        .not_valid_after(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC) + datetime.timedelta(days=365))
        .sign(private_key, None)
    )

    pem_cert = cert.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)
    return pem_cert

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cert = generate_minimal_certificate()
    print(cert.decode())
    print(len(cert))

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIGrMF+gAwIBAgIBATAFBgMrZXAwADAeFw0yNDExMTYxMDI4MzNaFw0yNTExMTYx
MDI4MzNaMAAwKjAFBgMrZXADIQCf30GvRnHbs9gukA3DLXDK6W5JVgYw6mERU/60
2M8+rjAFBgMrZXADQQCGmeaRp/AcjeqmJrF5Yh4d7aqsMSqVZvfGNDc0ppXyUgS3
WMQ1+3T+/pkhU612HR0vFd3vyFhmB4yqFoNV8RML
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


openssl req, 518 493 bytes
-25 bytes: --set-serial 1 by user7610
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBUTCB/qADAgECAhRuvWYi4YQN7neCssfB+Rsq+yMv5TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
ADAAMB4XDTI0MTExNTExMTQxNVoXDTI0MTExNjExMTQxNVowADBZMA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBAQUAA0gAMEUCPgLItpCnD7Ul4vED7loyin38YYetYx4MjeqQNPv6Ri9cvub7
giiduROYMed8ZbXm4h33knJNzVh+RWwnlhY7AgMBAAGjUzBRMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSJ
ST+wBPwEsQqLEDRgo4A0cuugGDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSJST+wBPwEsQqLEDRgo4A0
cuugGDAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAAz8AAeLZkP0i1rMQ
4D2Nt8DdKZgIESBzpFyPI17QR8kqypOdx43Tn+btsB6gAoqhv69GDSFxMtYw+90A
/S/+Fns=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
generated using:
openssl req -nodes -x509 -key key490.pem -days 1 -subj "/" --set-serial 1> cert.pem

with key490.pem a 490-bit rsa key generated using:
import rsa
import sys
pubkey,privkey = rsa.newkeys(int(sys.argv[1]))
print(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM').decode('UTF-8'))

While 512 bits is the smallest openssl will allow you to generate, an RSA key can be as small as 16 bits (!). However, as the key gets smaller, you can encrypt less and less data with it, and openssl is not happy about that. I performed a manual binary search between 16 and 512 to find that 490 bits is the smallest possible key using this technique.

@KevinCruijssen: even using 365 days makes no difference, i think the format stores unix timestamps for the beggining and end times. i could remove it but it wouldn't change anything.

Ah sorry, I misread the challenge. The size of the code doesn't matter, but the output certificate. Mb, ignore my comments (I'll delete them except for this one).

openssl req, 737 558 526 497 392 bytes
% openssl ecparam -name secp112r1 > ec.params                                          
% openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey ec:ec.params -days 1 -set_serial 1 -out ca-cert.pem -subj "/"

With the above I am getting certs that are either 392 or 396 bytes long. So I picked one of the shorter ones.
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIH2MIHBoAMCAQICAQEwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwADAeFw0yNDExMTUxODMzMjFaFw0y
NDExMTYxODMzMjFaMAAwMjAQBgcqhkjOPQIBBgUrgQQABgMeAAQ5m1Yk+0ZvpZWY
rCwQ4VBB54eR+XUcHcqsHfEmo1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUI3lNljOTV7EyOCeIadTV
9dmqMx0wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUI3lNljOTV7EyOCeIadTV9dmqMx0wDwYDVR0TAQH/
BAUwAwEB/zAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgMkADAhAg4UpmaNZ5cNCi8I9JkAswIPAM25KTiV
t33Lue3ZYVo/
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

changelog

-newkey rsa:512, use smallest possible private key size
-subj "/", the / seems to be the shortest possible accepted argument for -subj
-set_serial 1, the default is a large random number that takes up bytes
-newkey ec:ec.params, picked an elliptic curve from the list openssl ecparam -list_curves that is giving me the smallest key, after trying each once
-days 1, does not seem to have impact, but smaller numbers are usually better, copied from Themoonisacheese's answer


i'll let you have that one, i don't think i can beat this lol
